# Have a view modified according to network data on another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am developping an Android application which is supposed to manage a simple TCP connection through the `Socket` class. However, due to the fact that we cannot use network on the UI thread, I have to detach all network communication to a separate thread.

Basically, I have:

- My activity, the layout of which contains a `TextView`. The `TextView` is suppose to hold the connection log: messages I send, and those I receive from the server.
- My `Runnable` connection class, to which I associated a socket, and a few others methods to handle message reception. Everything in there runs in a separate thread.

Now, the tricky part is connecting the two. Since the messages do not arrive on the same thread as the UI runs, I cannot update the UI from the "network thread". If I do, I get an expectable...

```
CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

Now, this means that instead of "sending" the messages to the `TextView`, I should wait for them in the Activity. Basically, in my `onCreate`...

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    private MyConnectionClass connection;

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set up the activity, the UI listeners, and so on...
    TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(/* ... */);

    String serverMessage;
    while((serverMessage = connection.waitForMessage()) != null)
        myTextView.setText(myTextView.getText() + "\n" + message);
}
```

Here, we can assimilate `MyConnectionClass` to a `Socket` around which I added a few methods (it does not inherit `Socket` once implemented). Basically, `waitForMessage()` blocks until a message is received, and returns it when it arrives.

However, the problem here is that the waiting is done on the UI thread, and since I'm in `onCreate`, my activity hangs and never shows up.

I've tried a few solutions such as the `Observable` class and the `Observer` interface, but it does not eliminate the problem, since `notifyObservers` is called by the network thread, meaning that the UI update (done in `Observer.update()`) fails (`CalledFromWrongThreadException`).

I also tried waiting on another thread started by the activity, but quickly realised I would get the result as above... Besides, I'm not sure I really need to create again another new thread.

Considering that the UI thread is the only one which can modify the `TextView`, and since I cannot really afford to "freeze" my UI, is there a way I could have my network thread update the UI's `TextView` asynchronously when messages arrive?

Comment: To modify the UI components from secondary thread, you need handler. Read this link https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity Oncreate Method or any appropriate method, where you need to start the network operation, add this line.

```
new NetworkOperation().execute("");
```

Add this class

```
private class NetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // Do your network connection
            return "Value";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.YOURTEXTVIEW);
            txt.setText("Executed"); // txt.setText(result);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {}

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, since this is a TCP connection, my `AsyncTask` wouldn't terminate (`postExecute`) until the connection is closed. This is why I'm using an actual `Thread` and not the `AsyncTask` wrapper class.